# XAML Parsing Failed in Windows Store App (KinectV2)

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, kinect

I am trying to integrate a Kinect V2 sensor in a Windows Store App (Windows 8.1), but I am experiencing a really strange problem: if I add an item of type KinectRegion to the XAML, Visual Studio 2013 raises a ***XAML Parsing Failed*** error, and underlines the KinectRegion.

Here you can find my XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="Windows_App.Screen.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Windows_App.Screen"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:kinect="using:Microsoft.Kinect.Xaml.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="RootWindow" Background="#45B6E7">
    <kinect:KinectRegion></kinect:KinectRegion>
</Grid>
```

The strangest thing is that the IntelliSense suggests and allows me to autocomplete the insertion of the KinectRegion, and i can find the KinectRegion item it in the Toolbox items list.

Any idea on what problem is going on, here?